# Какая команда помогает сделать скринЛок на СиШарп?

Tags: c#, wpf

Я пишу винлокер на **C#** и я никак не могу понять как заблокировать экран.

Comment: Симулируйте нажатие Win+L. Отправлять Explorer -у

Comment: Вот ответ с англоязычного SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13745833/6468198

Answer (score 0):

Обычный пинвок LockWorkStation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-lockworkstation

Comment: Это больше похоже на комментарий, чем на ответ. Может быть, стоит включить больше подробностей в ответ (например, как вызвать такую функцию в C# коде) ?